# Why the datetime becomes a number? How can I make the datetime format in result?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am making the api with flask but I get a issue.
I don't know why the datetime becomes a number?
This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, g, render_template, request, jsonify, json, current_app, redirect, url_for
from flask import make_response
import flask
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
import logging
import os
import chardet
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import tempfile


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/tier_change',methods = ['POST'])
def index3():
    VIP_CODE = request.form['VIP_CODE']
    CHANGE_TYPE = request.form['CHANGE_TYPE']
    CHANGE_TIME = request.form['CHANGE_TIME']
    BEFORE_TIER_CODE = request.form['BEFORE_TIER_CODE']
    AFTER_TIER_CODE = request.form['AFTER_TIER_CODE']
    BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE = request.form['BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE']
    AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE = request.form['AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE']
    a = {'VIP_CODE': [VIP_CODE],
        'CHANGE_TYPE':[CHANGE_TYPE],
        'CHANGE_TIME':[CHANGE_TIME],
        'BEFORE_TIER_CODE':[BEFORE_TIER_CODE],
        'AFTER_TIER_CODE':[AFTER_TIER_CODE],
        'BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE':[BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE],
        'AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE':[AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
    df['New_date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df['New_date_start'] = df['New_date_start'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1) - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
    result = df.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    if parsed:
        print(df)
        print(result)
        print(parsed)
        print(json.dumps(parsed))
        return json.dumps(parsed) 
    else:
        return 'not valid'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5010)
```

Sample input:

```
VIP_CODE:03K100000882
CHANGE_TYPE:Renew
BEFORE_TIER_CODE:FO
AFTER_TIER_CODE:FO
BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE:2021-09-04
AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE:2022-09-04
CHANGE_TIME:2021-09-07
```

And the result:

```
[{"VIP_CODE":"03K100000882","CHANGE_TYPE":"Renew","CHANGE_TIME":"2021-09-07","BEFORE_TIER_CODE":"FO","AFTER_TIER_CODE":"FO","BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE":"2021-09-04","AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE":"2022-09-04","New_date_start":1630627200000}]
```

The New_date_start is number. It was a date. And I have checked the dateframe.
The New_date_start is date format.
This is df:

```
       VIP_CODE CHANGE_TYPE CHANGE_TIME BEFORE_TIER_CODE AFTER_TIER_CODE BEFORE_EXPIRED_DATE AFTER_EXPIRED_DATE New_date_start
0  03K100000882       Renew  2021-09-07               FO              FO          2021-09-04         2022-09-04     2021-09-03
```

How can I fix this? And what happened in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(['datetime']).astype(str).to_dict('list')).to_json(orient="records")
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation